# Probability that a set of $n(n+1)/2$ elements will contain $1... n$ elements, respectively, of $n$ possibilities

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We opened a 'fun size' bag of Skittles this afternoon, and it contained 5 yellow, 4 red, 3 blue, 2 green, and 1 purple Skittle. If the Skittles only come in these 5 colors, they are chosen randomly from a vat with an infinite number of each color, and each bag contains 15 Skittles, what are the chances that there will be one color with each cardinality between 1 and 5? (Which color has which cardinality is immaterial)

Generalize for $n$ colors and $n(n+1)/2$ Skittles per bag.

P.S. I just realized that Skittles also come in orange... let's pretend that they don't for the purposes of this puzzle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular colour pattern you described has probability
$$\binom{15}{1,2,3,4,5}\cdot \frac{1}{5^{15}}.$$
Here we are using the *Multinomial Distribution* (please see Wikipedia).

For the probability of a $1,2,3,4,5$ distribution, multiply by $5!$, the number of permutations of the colours.

Comment: This probability turns out to be .14878, somewhat higher than I expected.

Comment: In Bridge also, unbalanced distributions, particularly with computer-dealt hands, occur more frequently than intuition suggests.

Comment: Are computer-generated bridge hands differently random than those (properly) shuffled by hand?

Comment: Proper hand shuffling is very difficult to do. When computer generated hands came in, there were many complaints about the "weirdness" of the hands.